# IE keeps throwing an error but my $ is defined and even on document.ready

Tags: jquery

When I run this in chrome it works fine but in IE it throws the error listed above. What am I doing wrong? I included the jquery and I even defined the $.

Here is the error.
The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

```
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script type='text/javascript'  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script type='text/javascript'  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />


 <script type='text/javascript' >
        $(document).ready(function ($) { // $ here binds the name in this scope
            $("input:radio").change(function () {
                var selectedText = $("input:radio:checked").attr('id');
                if (selectedText === "button_1" && document.getElementById("button_0").checked === false) {
                    $('#ex1').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: did you close the last script tag ?

Comment: yes i did use one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the $ into the function ,because js will look for the argument of the function. Even it will change your jquery - $ variable into expected argument, which is undefined, so the jQuery will stop to work then. Remove the $ from function.

```
$(document).ready(function () { // remove $ from ()
```

You can also use the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

If jQuery is in the document scope but the $ is still not defined, try to use different function call. It will declare jQuery as $ explicilty.

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I still get the same error. It has to do with the $ at the very front

Comment: Maybe those script somehow slow down the jquery load, try to load the jquery from the cdn right before your script

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere. The $ error went away but now it is saying - "jQuery" is undefined

Comment: also this cdn may be slow or blocked, try to use google cdn for example `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> `

Comment: Jquery is still undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I was including the jquery at the bottom of my code and when i moved it to the very top everything started working.

Comment: try to search a little bit more. jQuery could be included at the bottom, then the js scripts don't block website rendering.